# Learning React.js - Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

I am learning react.js. I used to develope front-end with jquery in past , but now I see that things had drasticly changed from that time. 
I managed to create my firt component - search bar. So I wanted to add i18next to my app using react-i18next.

After followig some tutorial I did following:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import XHR from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

    i18n
        .use(XHR)
        .use(LanguageDetector)
        .init({
            fallbackLng: 'en',

            // have a common namespace used around the full app
            ns: ['common'],
            defaultNS: 'common',

            debug: true,

            backend: {
                // path where resources get loaded from
                loadPath: 'assets/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',

                // path to post missing resources
                addPath: 'assets/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.missing.json',

                // jsonIndent to use when storing json files
                jsonIndent: 2
            }


        });
        ReactDOM.render(
        <I18nextProvider i18n={ i18n }>
        <App />
        </I18nextProvider>    ,
        document.getElementById('content')
    );
```

however, I am getting error:

```
main.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

and line in compiled js file that contains error has:

```
var _i18next = require('i18next');
```

Comment: I think that you need to use some sort of bundler, such as webpack or browserify (browserify is easier to get started with). `require` is not a browser built-in.

Comment: do you use nodejs to serve your front end ?